# Why is Pathname not considered a string (or when is it okay to add a to_str method to a class)?

Tags: ruby

There was a bug report [Pathname#to_str doesn't appear to work anymore](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1970). Having `to_str` in Pathname would let you use Pathname anywhere you use a string, eg with `Dir`, `system`, etc. However the bug report was rejected, and it appears from a commit message that the `to_str` method was deliberately removed.

I don't understand this - Pathname can be loselessly converted to a String and back, and it would be very convenient when working with APIs that don't use Pathname.

So why is having `to_str` not appropriate for Pathname, and when is `to_str` okay to use?

Comment: Good question. [This discussion](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/96554) of the difference between `to_s` and `to_str` specifically cites Pathname as a reason for having `to_str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an article](http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/2008/02/ruby-duck-typing-effect.html) that attempts to answer your question but, in my opinion, doesn't really succeed.

Around the same time `Pathname#to_str` was removed `Exception#to_str` was [removed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/ce44928d2b4d32b41f9a19097fb7bd7b2c13c4bd) as well--clearly Matz was trying to draw a line in the sand at this time between "stringlike" and "non-stringlike" classes. The `Exception` change makes sense--an Exception cannot, to use your words, "be losslessly converted to a String and back," because an Exception object contains lots of other information--the stack trace in particular--that would be lost in that conversion.

I can only guess but I'd wager that Matz felt the same way about `Pathname`, though it's unclear why. Even to documentation (1.9.3) at one point, says (under "Core methods"), "These methods are effectively manipulating a String, because that’s all a path is." Several sources I've found--in addition to the one @MarkThomas cites--use `Pathname` as an example of a class for which `to_str` *does* make sense, probably taking a cue from Hal Fulton's *The Ruby Way*.

I guess this isn't a very satisfactory answer. If you really want to know you may have to ask on [Ruby-Talk or Ruby-Core](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/). You could try asking Matz [on Twitter](Yukihiro Matsumoto), but he seems to converse exclusively in Japanese. [Wycats](https://twitter.com/#!/wycats) and [Jeremy Kemper](https://twitter.com/#!/bitsweat) may have some more insight, though, and seem pretty accessible. Good luck!

P.S. [This article](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2010/07/we-need-syntax-for-talking-about-ruby.html) has a section "Technical explanation of `to_str` and friends" that I found interesting, but it doesn't do any better a job of answering your question.